# How to upload App Icon for iPad Pro in Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, ipad, icons, xcode7

I've seen 1 answer on this site to add **CFBundleIconFiles~ipad** in info.plist but it didn't work for me.

How does Apple say to add App Icon for iPad Pro ? I can't find a way.

Comment: Just add the 76pt 2x icon to the Asset/AppIcon.

Comment: You're talking about the iPad Mini app icon, I'm talking about iPad PRO. I don't know where to put iPad Pro App icons.